# Connection Timeout on aws when Telnet on Port 25

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, timeout, postfix-mta, mail-server

Thanks you for your time.

I have just set up a Postfix mail server which is running as MTA in one of my aws instances. I can successfully connect to the localhost through 'telnet localhost 25', and I can send emails to both external and internal email accounts when connected on localhost, however whenever I try to connect through 'telnet zwitch.it 25' or 'telnet mail.zwitch.it 25' I get a connection timeout.

I have set up all my records, including the MX record and the SPF record with the values "v=spf1 include:amazonses.com include:zwitch.it -all" and "spf2.0/pra include:amazonses.com include:zwitch.it ~all".

I really cannot find what is the problem here, if there is a firewall, or if the port is blocked, or maybe something is wrong with my postfix configuration... I would really appreciate if you could help me.

To set up my postfix mail server I followed the instructions at http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/ where it mentions the installation of a simple postfix server.

I thank you in advance for the help.

EDIT: 
Thanks to the answer below the problem was fixed. I only had to go on my aws security groups and add SMTP to the list!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If any of the suggestions are helpful do not forget to up vote and or mark a response as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one of three things:

1.) You need to edit your security group in AWS to allow port 25 from all external IP addresses.

2.) Your DNS entries for mail.zwitch.it do not point to the external IP address of the AWS instance.

3.) You don't have a static IP (elastic) address configured for the instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I have right now in my route53: http://postimg.org/image/wjyo79ma9/ I dont think that there is an error with the elastic ip, but as I dont really know much about this maybe I have an error on my MX or in my SPF address. Otherwise, could I ask, where are the security group options - is this on the IAM section?

Comment: The security groups are under the EC2 section - check that. This is an error with you not being able to 'get' to the server from the outside world. MX settings and SPF records only control mail flow.

Comment: Oh, port 25 is not included http://postimg.org/image/z4pgc85c9/ - do you think this might be the problem? I'll try to include it now, is there any specific options I should choose to include it?

Comment: That is the problem. Add port 25 and leave the source as 0.0.0.0/0 and you should be good to go.

Comment: Ok, now I can connect locally using mail.zwitch.it, which was not possible before, but I still cannot connect from a remote computer - I get a connection timeout, would this problem be in my master.cf file? or a problem with aws? Here is the image, on the left I am ssh'ed and on the right its from the remote computer http://postimg.org/image/biobnawuh/83239a26/

Comment: I can connect to it from here http://postimg.org/image/qp3two81d/1afae853/ So it is set up correctly.

Comment: Oh amazing, what command are you trying to use to connect? I am using 'telnet mail.zwitch.it 25' but there is no success... So now if I send an email to an account@zwitch.it should that now work?

Comment: I used 'telnet mail.zwitch.it 25'. Not sure about getting the email to send - that is where your MX, SPF records and postfix configuration will come into play.

Comment: Wooo it's working now!! Well I still can't telnet from this computer, but the emails are working!! Thank you very much bro! Saved my life! have a great day man!

Comment: I'd upvote you bro, but I need more reputation to be able to...

Comment: No problem. Can you mark the question as answered? (Click check box) Have a good one!

Comment: Oh man, I did not think about the __Security Group__. That's what fixed it for me.